# Cross section with orography

Tags: python, matplotlib

First of all, I've looked at these links:

[Contouring non-uniform 2d data in python/matplotlib above terrain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35493275/contouring-non-uniform-2d-data-in-python-matplotlib-above-terrain)

[Cross-section plotting with terrain as background](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36502443/cross-section-plotting-with-terrain-as-backgroun)

[Matplotlib axis labels: how to find out where they will be located?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14153816/matplotlib-axis-labels-how-to-find-out-where-they-will-be-locatedd)

but unsuccessfully solve my problem.

As you can see from this image (ignore the wrong title, it's actually zonal winds):

[image: zonal winds with hybrid level]

where the black line is the orography and the shaded contour is zonal wind values, the winds value at near sea level, at for example 101.5 E, is under the terrain/orography instead of on top.

At this point, the data used to produce that plot are:

1. zonal winds data with 814x70 shape. (814-longitude, 70-height)
2. orography with 814x1 shape (basically a list of terrain height)

I wonder if I can manipulate something, to plot the data following the terrain. Some suggest grid interpolation or interpolation in general, but I've been scratching my head on how to get it works.

Answer (score 0):

I've had this problem too - it is quite tricky to get the terrain to follow orography. I tried manually adding in orography using the surface altitude variable I had in my model output but it was too computationally intensive (at least with the number of model levels and the resolution I have).

I don't know what format your files are in, or what kind of data you're using but have you tried looking at the module iris? It includes a method of adding orography into profiles when it loads files (HybridHeightFactory). Link here: http://scitools.org.uk/iris/

Comment: I did look at the module iris, and unable to install it on my Mac (however, it is there in the Uni's server). So, I never tried, will probably do later in the future if I am able to install it again. I stay with all pressure-level data. They are all converted to netcdf.